# ¿Eclipse o Android Studio? cual es mejor para desarrollo de aplicaciones con libreria OpenCV

Tags: android, android-studio, linux, windows, eclipse

En Kali Linux programo con Eclipse Neon en NDK pero no logro hacer que la librería OpenCV que importé, se añada como librería de mi proyecto.
Cual IDE es mejor para programar con la librería OpenCV? considerando la versión de la IDE y la versión de OpenCV.

Comment: con qt puedes usar opencv y tienes soporte para android

Comment: Te recomendaría sin duda Android Studio y habilitar el soporte nativo para tu proyecto.  En ambas opciones puedes instalar :
http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html 
No debes tener problema al usar OpenCV con Eclipse y el plugin de android!. La terminación oficial del soporte para el plugin Android en Eclipse se debe considerar por lo tanto la recomendación es Android Studio.

Comment: Agregue mi opinion como comentario....

Comment: Porque desean reabrir esta pregunta? "Muchas buenas preguntas generan cierto grado de opinión según la experiencia de los expertos, pero casi todas las respuestas a esta pregunta estarán basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos, referencias o experiencia específica."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normalmente esta tipo pregunta llamaría a respuestas "puro basado en opiniones", pero en este caso no lo es.

Fin de 2015 Google terminó el soporte por el plugin ADT para eclipse, tal cual para el sistema de build Ant.
En un anuncio del 26. de junio 2015 Google recomendó de migrar projectos de Eclipse a Android Studio.

La ultima versión de ADT ya no trabaja con las versiónes actuales de Android SDK.

Así entre Eclipse y Android Studio, lamentablemente ya no te queda elección, si no te quieres limitar a producir para versiones obsoletas de Android - entre los dos, Android Studio tiene que ser.

[Fuente oficial en ingles](https://developer.android.com/studio/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html)